# Construction of the Associated projective hyperplane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projective-space

Let $V$ be $K-$vector space of dimension $n$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane given by the kernel of the linear map
$l_H:V\longrightarrow K$ defined by
$$l_H(x)=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$$
where $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are the coordinates of $x$ in a chosen basis of $V$.

Let $P(V)$ be the projective space associated to $V$. Consider the map: $l_{H'}:P(V)\longrightarrow K$
defined by
$$l_{H'}([x_1:\cdots:x_n])=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$$
Does the kernel of $l_{H'}$ defines a projective hyperplane in $P(V)$?

Comment: A linear map $T:V\to W$ has to be injective to extend as a map on $P(V)\to P(W)$. Here, $l_{H'}$ is not well-defined, since the coordinates can be multiplied by any scalar.

Comment: Yes I see that, could you please tell me how to construct the associated projective hyperplane?

Comment: The hyperplane is the set of points $[x_1:\cdots:x_n]$ such that $l_h(x)=0$.

Comment: Can we say that every projective hypeplane $H\in P(V)$ is given as $H=\{[x_1:\cdots:x_n]\in P(V) \,|\, a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0\}$ for some given scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in K$?

Comment: @palio Yes (in regards to your comment), this is immediate from the definition of the projective space; the hyperplanes of the projective space are in 1-1 correspondence with the hyperplanes of the underlying vector space.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes. A point $M \in P(V)$ belongs to the projective hyperplane $P(H)$ if and only if one of its representative, $\vec{M} \in H \iff l_H(\vec{M}) = 0$ (which is an equation of $P(H)$.